# How many ways to arrange $n$ viruses on the $n \times n$ grid?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's take a look at a classic intelligence problem first.

**Consider an $n\times n$ grid, and call two cells with common edges adjacent cells. Initially, there were viruses in some cells. Every second, if a cell has at least two adjacent(Two lattices with common edges are called adjacent lattices) cells infected with the virus, it will also become infected. In order to make all cells infected, how many cells with virus are needed at least at the beginning?**

Answer: At least $n$, such as for example $n$ cells on a diagonal. $n$ cells are also required. When a new cell is infected, the perimeter of the figure composed of all infected cells will be reduced by $0$, $2$ or $4$ units (the specific reduction depends on the number of infected cells around it). And because when all the cells are infected, the perimeter of the figure is $4n$, so there must be at least $n$ infected cells at the beginning.

Now the question is, when we put $n$ viruses into the $n\times n$ grid, how many ways are there such that the whole board gets infected? (rotation and overturning are not considered)

Comment: It's a little hard to follow because when you write "grid" or "lattice" you actually mean "cell" or "square".

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis  sorry sir,my first language is not English ,I use translate machine to communicate,so there maybe something wrong.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis Sir,I think it is the Large Schröder numbers.

Comment: No, for n=3 there are more than 6 ways that work. I count 14 arrangements: the 6 with one virus in each row and each column; 4 ways that have three of the corner cells; 4 ways that have one side cell and the two opposite corners. There may be others I'm overlooking.

Comment: Two lattices with common edges are called adjacent lattices,I forget to add this condition.It is the original condition of this intelligence problem.Sorry for it.

Comment: OEIS: [A146971](http://oeis.org/A146971) expressly answers your question.

Comment: If the viruses are like the rooks and can not attack each other ,the answer is the Large Schröder numbers